# Quadratics, transformations, and formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, transformation

Two-part question. Feel free to answer just one part, or both (write which letter part you are answering)

> a) If the quadratic function $g(x)=a(x-h)^2+ k$ does not touch the $x$-axis, what can be said about $a$ and $k$? There are two cases.

I'm having trouble explaining the cases.
**Please use transformations to explain the answer**

So far, I only know the basics of $k$ shifting the graph up, so if $k$ does not touch the $x$-axis, it is any real number except $0$. I also know $a$ can be any real number, making the graph taller or wider.
What else can be said about $a$ and $k$?

> b) If the quadratic function $g(x)=a(x-h)^2+ k$ touches the $x$-axis exactly once, what can you say about $a$ and $k$?

Comment: There is a difference if $a$ is positive or negative

Comment: I noticed earlier today you asked a question about factorising $x^2+7$. I tried to answer it by explaining what mathematicians mean by "exact" and that $\sqrt{7}$ is an exact number. You deleted the question before I could post my answer. Are you able to say why you deleted it? It was a valid question and might help others. While I'm at it, I hope you don't mind if I point out that it helps people who are trying to help you if you use the voting buttons and select the answer that you think helped you the most.

Comment: @GeoffPointer I'm really sorry, I didn't see your answer. There were only a few comments on it, no answers yet, so I thought that deleting it wouldn't do anything. I had realized my mistake in the problem by myself so since no one was answering I deleted. Next time I will keep it posted up! Sorry.

Comment: That's okay, no need to apologise. This site does not have personal messages, so it's hard to communicate outside of the actual question pages. It's probably better to leave a comment that you've figured it out. You're also allowed to answer your own questions. [Read this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). There are other help pages about how to vote for questions and answers and so on you can find them in the help centre which is linked from the help menu at the top of the page.

Comment: BTW, now that your reputation is over 15, you can vote for questions and answers using the up arrows. You can up vote questions you think are good or interesting and even though you can still only "accept" one answer of course, you can up vote all of the answers that you believe help you or are helpful in general as well.

Comment: I've added some notes about the topic of transformations to my answer as per your bolded request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is a parabola. If a>0, then the parabola goes up and k has to be k>0 so that the vertex is above the x-axis. (The vertex is (h,k) and k moves the vertex up in this case)
If a<0, then the parabola goes down and k has to be k<0 so that the vertex is below the x-axis. (k moves the vertex down in this case--because k is neg.
Those are the two cases: when a>0 and when a<0.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Personally, I prefer the simplest solution, which often highlights an important fundamental concept. We're dealing with an inequality here, so a handy point to notice in this case is that $(x-h)^2\ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Note: I have edited this answer to include some references to the topic of transformations as this aspect has been highlighted in the OP. Hopefully this hasn't obscured my main point as mentioned above.

Hence, either (i) $a(x-h)^2 \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ if $a>0$ or (ii) $a(x-h)^2 \le 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ if $a<0$.

Now, $a(x-h)^2 = 0$ when $x=h$, so there's a point when the graph would touch the x-axis, if $k = 0$.

In terms of transformations, if $y = f(x)$ in general, then $y = f(x) + k$ is a vertical translation in the direction of the sign of $k$. If $k>0$, it translates upwards, if $k<0$ it translates downwards.

So, in case (i), $k>0$ would mean an upward translation and $a(x-h)^2 + k > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. In case (ii), $k<0$ would mean a downward translation and $a(x-h)^2 + k < 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

As in each case, with $k=0$ there would be one point on the graph touching the $x$-axis, the translation takes the graph in the appropriate direction away from the $x$-axis so as not to intersect.

With $y=af(x)$, we have an enlargement if $a>0$. If $a<0$ it is an enlargement combined with a reflection in the $x$-axis. An important point in this problem is that the enlargement doesn't change the basic solution because if $f(x)=0$ then $af(x)=0$ and the reflection just gives us the alternative case.

The answer to (b) is contained within my answer to (a).

Note: There is of course the trivial case of a=0, but I'll leave you to ponder that.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is correct. The same reasoning applies to both the problems.To know more about the relation between a and k you will have to use algebra. 
For the first case the discriminant has to be less than 0 and for the second the discriminant has to be 0.

$$g(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$$
$$\Rightarrow g(x)=ax^2-2axh+k+ah^2$$

If g(x) never touches the x-axis, it means there exists no value of x for which g(x)=0 and if g(x) touches the x-axis it would imply that there is only one value of x for which g(x)=0.For discriminant [click me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is this for question part a, when the graph does not touch the x-axis at all? also, by discriminant do you mean h?

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to GTX OC's answer. Please give him/her the credit. Also, upvote any answer that *helps* you and accept any that solves the problem. I think GTX gave the answer but here is some more explanation.

From what GTX wrote

$$
 g(x)=ax^2-2axh+k+ah^2$$

The discriminant is 
$$
\Delta = (2 a h)^2 - 4 a (k+a h^2) = -4 a k$$

Now we have three cases
$$
\Delta ~~\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    < 0, & \hbox{$g(x)$ does not touch the $x$ axis;} \\
    =0, & \hbox{$g(x)$ touches $x$ axis exactly at one point;} \\
    >0, & \hbox{$g(x)$ crosses $x$ axis at two points.}
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Now $a \neq 0$ for it to be a quadratic. So what can you say about $k$ in each of the cases?

*I realize you are new here.* All of us do this because we want to help. So do the right thing and vote up any answer that helps you and accept any that you feel is the best for your needs.